# Email template : Get instance url

Tags: email, email-template, url

I have an email template that has some static links (URL) that points to our instance of Salesforce. Is there a way to get the instance URL dynamically? This template is not being called from Apex code. so can't programmatically replace anything.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Email Templates don't currently give you this ability, however you can create a custom formula field on the object you're merging (assuming you're merging an object) that can merge in the org specific URL.

E.g create a formula field with a formula of:

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_550, FIND('/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_550))
```